# Domain filter operator for XML attrs in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

There is my problem,
I got:

```
(A and B) or (C and D)
```

In domain i write:

```
[ '|', (A, B), (C, D) ]
```

But it not work, and raise error:

> Error: Unknown field document_receive_type,!=,vn_post in domain
>   ["|",[["document_receive_type","!=","direct"],["state","!=","vn_post_check"]],[["document_receive_type","!=","vn_post"],["state","!=","result_profile_returned"]]]

Here is my code:

```
<button name="action_mark_done"
    string="Mark Done"
    type="object" class="oe_highlight"
    attrs="{'invisible': ['|', (('document_receive_type','!=','direct'), ('state', '!=', 'vn_post_check')), (('document_receive_type','!=','vn_post'), ('state', '!=', 'result_profile_returned')) ,]}"
    groups="bms_cpdt.group_e_gov_manager"/>
```

I've tried individually

```
['&', (A), (B),]
```

or

```
['&', (C), (D),]
```

it still work and show my button but if

```
['|', '&', (A), (B),'&',(C),(D)]
```

it has no error but it is not show my button like i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(A and B) or (C and D)
```

If you want to get that, your domain would be:

```
['|', '&', (A), (B),'&',(C),(D)]
```

And with your data:

```
['|', '&amp;', ('document_receive_type','!=','direct'), ('state', '!=', 'vn_post_check'),'&amp;',('document_receive_type','!=','vn_post'),('state', '!=', 'result_profile_returned')]
```

For more information about domains you can visit:
[domain-notation](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/domain-notation-using-multiple-and-nested-and-2170)

I hope I've helped

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
attrs="{'invisible': ['|', '&amp;',('document_receive_type','!=','direct'), ('state', '!=', 'vn_post_check'), '&amp;', ('document_receive_type','!=','vn_post'), ('state', '!=', 'result_profile_returned')]}"
```

Comment: thank you but it is not work,
i've tried ['&', (A), (B),] and ['&', (C), (D),] individually, it still work and show my button
but if ['|', '&', (A), (B),'&',(C),(D)] , it has no error but it is not show my button :(

Comment: but did you write '&amp;' instead of '&'?

Comment: ok, tkx you, i used 
attrs="{'invisible': ['!','|', '&amp;',('document_receive_type','=','direct'), ('state', '=', 'vn_post_check'), '&amp;', ('document_receive_type','=','vn_post'), ('state', '=', 'result_profile_returned')]}"
and it worked

Comment: Cool, then you can mark the answer like the right one. Glad to help